# How to use pygame.sprite.collide_rect_ratio()

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision, rect

I have no idea how to use it not even after reading the pygame documentation. I've searched all over and can't find it nowhere. Can someone please explain ot to me?

Comment: Do you have a specific use case you struggle with? Do you have some code?

Answer (score 0):

`sprite.collide_rect_ratio(ratio)`, as I gather from the documentation and [examples on GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=pygame.sprite.collide_rect_ratio&type=Code&l=Python), checks to see if two sprite objects have collided up to a certain amount (ie. this will return `True` if you check two objects for a collision with `.5` as the ratio, then move one sprite over halfway inside the other).

This is commonly used, syntactically, with the `sprite.group_collide()` function or double-parenthesis (Ex. [Double Parenthesis in Python](https://oswalt.dev/2015/05/double-parentheses-in-python/)) to get the result.

Also, be sure to look through the GitHub examples along with the documentation, it'll provide more context on how to use the function; this post is likely to be downvoted because of lack of research beforehand, so keep this in mind when asking questions in the future.

Comment: I found what i was looking for. Your answer did help me. Thanks alot, if i could i would give you a upvote and I'll try asking better questions in tge futur. Thanks